# How can i use external js librry in a project of next js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to user external javascript library like jquery , boostrap , flexnav in my project using next js framework. it's not working. My code is following ,

```
import React from 'react'
import MainMenu from './MainMenu'
import Head from 'next/head'
import MobileMenu from './MobileMenu'
import Image from 'next/image'

export const Header = () => {
    return (
<header className="clear-fix"> 
            <Head>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js" ></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.flexnav.min.js" ></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/owl.carousel.min.js" ></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/custom.js"></script>
            </Head>
```

Anyone please help to find a solution of this issue.

Comment: `<head>` tag should go before `<body>` (as all creatures has it that way)

Comment: You can look here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61029733/integrating-a-jquery-plugin-into-nextjs) This can help you

Comment: There are 2 different subjects: loading jQuery and using it in React components. Can you tell us more about what is not working? How do you tell, what is the error etc.

Comment: @EricBurel i am using next js framework of react and i want to add these js files above in  a react component. When i am adding these js in html file it's working fine but when i am adding the same html code i a react component with those js then it's not working.

Comment: Hi, you need to be very clear so we can help you. Can you please update your question with the error messages you encounter for example, and examples of your failing code?

Comment: This problem have been solved now. It was an issue with jQuery.