# Next.js "jQuery requires a window with a document", defining jsdom yields Unexpected token

Tags: jquery, next.js

I started with the following code, which is intended to create a multi-select button box using Tailwind and DaisyUI in Next.js (The filename of the problematic code snippet is install.js).

I'm rendering it with webpack by running `npx next`, and `index.js` works perfectly. However, `install.js`is not rendered, and shows a "jQuery requires a window..." error.

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';

export default function Home() {
  return (
      <div class="flex-1 p-10 w-full max-w-4xl my-2">
        (function ($, cmdMap) {
          var cmdTxt = $('.command .text');
          var opts = {
            version: 'stable (recommended)',
            pm: 'pip',
            gpu: 'YES',
          };
          function buildMatcher() {
            return opts.version.toLowerCase() + ',' + opts.pm.toLowerCase() + ','
              + opts.gpu.toLowerCase()
          }
          function updateCommand() {
            var match = cmdMap[buildMatcher(opts)];
            cmdTxt.html(match);
          }
          function selectOption(ev) {
            var el = $(this);
            el.siblings().removeClass('btn-active');
            el.addClass('btn-active');
            opts[el.parents('.option-row').data('key')] = el.text();
            updateCommand();
          }
          $('.option-set').on('click', '.btn', selectOption);
          updateCommand();
        }(jQuery, {
          'stable,conda,no': 'a string',
          /* ... */
        }))
        }
        <div class="shadow-lg mockup-code">
          <pre><code>{/* TODO: figure out what to put here */}</code></pre>
          <pre class="pt-3 link"><code><a href="help">What is this?</a></code></pre>
        </div>
        <div class="pt-5 btns">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-active">stable (recommended)</button>
            <button class="btn">nightly</button>
          </div>
          <div class="pt-3 btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-active">pip</button>
            <button class="btn">docker</button>
            <button class="btn">conda</button>
          </div>
          <div class="pt-3 btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-active">GPU Enabled</button>
            <button class="btn">No GPU</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Which yields the following server error: `Error: jQuery requires a window with a document` at line 14

```
  | (function ($, cmdMap) {
> |   var cmdTxt = $('.command .text');
                  ^
  |   var opts = {
```

When I followed the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358015/error-jquery-requires-a-window-with-a-document), by adding the following snippet at the specified line numbers:

```
7       var jsdom = require('jsdom');                                                                                                                                             
8       $ = require('jquery')(new jsdom.JSDOM().window);
```

I receive an unexpected token error. Sorry if this is silly, I'm really new to JS.

How should I proceed?

Edit: The jQuery function was non-critical for me so I ended up working around it. I still am not too clear on how to resolve this.

Comment: This looks like it can help! https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12124

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integrating a jQuery plugin into NextJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61029733/integrating-a-jquery-plugin-into-nextjs)

Comment: Thanks @juliomalves . I can't quite figure out how to apply that since its for a jQuery plugin and not jQuery code.

Comment: The jQuery function was non-critical for me so I ended up working around it. I still am not too clear on how to resolve this.