# Having trouble getting coverflow.js JQuery module to work in Next.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to use the JQuery library [coverflow.js](https://github.com/coverflowjs/coverflow) to work in Next.JS. Using the solution to [61029733](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61029733/integrating-a-jquery-plugin-into-nextjs/61040108#61040108) as a starting point (fresh clone of the [repo](https://github.com/tudorgergely/jquery-plugin-nextjs/)), I added `coverflow.min.js` to the `public` folder and added a single line to `JqueryDiamonds.js` as shown below:

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.jQuery = require('../public/jquery-latest.min');
    window.Diamonds = require('../public/jquery.diamonds.js');
    window.Coverflow = require("../public/coverflow.min.js");

    window.jQuery("#demo").diamonds({
        size : 100, // Size of diamonds in pixels. Both width and height.
        gap : 5, // Pixels between each square.
        hideIncompleteRow : false, // Hide last row if there are not enough items to fill it completely.
        autoRedraw : true, // Auto redraw diamonds when it detects resizing.
        itemSelector : `.${styles.item}` // the css selector to use to select diamonds-items.
    });
}, []);
```

I get the following runtime error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createElement')
```

The same happens if I use the un-minified version of Coverflow `coverflow.js`:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createElement')
at coverflow.js:2469:1
```

The code at this line is:

```
var el = document.createElement( "div" ),
```

I am very confused why `createElement`, a vanilla JavaScript function, is giving an error. Maybe it has something to do with `document` not being defined, however this shouldn't be happening since the way the component is being dynamically loaded disables SSR.

I know this is an old JQuery library, but I have been able to make it work by including the script in normal HTML instead of Next. There is a React package alternative to this JQuery library but that is not the solution I am looking for as it is inferior in many ways design wise.

Comment: Are you importing/using `coverflow` anywhere else in the app?

Comment: @juliomalves No, just in this file.